# Cheerio, axios, reactjs to web scrape a table off a webpage returning empty list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-scraping, axios, cheerio

Trying to scrape this table off this website: https://www.investing.com/commodities/real-time-futures

But for some reason when I try to get the data, I keep getting an empty list.

This is what I'm doing to get the data and parse it:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://www.investing.com/commodities/real-time-futures`)
      .then(response => {
        if(response.status === 200)
          {
            const html = response.data;
            const $ = cheerio.load(html);
            let data = [];
            $('#cross_rate_1 tr').each((i, elem) => {
                data.push({
                  Month: $(elem).find('td#left noWrap').text()
                })
            });
            console.log(data);
          }
        }, (error) => console.log('err') );
  }
```

This is a screenshot of the particular part of the source code I'm trying to scrape.

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The reason you are getting it empty is because they updates the list via a WebSocket connection, if you open your devtools > network > WS you will see the connection there. 

Comment: its coming up empty on the webpage and I only see a sockjs.node file in my localhost WS

Comment: The WebSocket connection I mentioned was in `https://www.investing.com/commodities/real-time-futures`, not in your local website.

Comment: Oh I see it there now, so is it just not possible to scrape the data? Because doing this in the console allows me to get all the values document.querySelectorAll("#cross_rate_1 td")].forEach(td => console.log(td.innerText))

Comment: Exactly, you are able to get the data from the console in `investing.com`, but when you do a fetch from your local website it don't has the data, so it will only get the empty html.

Comment: So is there no way to scrape the data?

Comment: As far as I can tell you, no, there isn't, but what you can try is to connect to their WebSocket from your local website, if they don't refuse your connection by a cors policy...

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, the table in question is constantly updating via a websocket connection. You can try getting the data by either 1) connecting to the websocket or 2) scraping the dynamically generated html.

Just for a data snapshot and not for a continuous time series, you can use a browser scraping extension. In this way you won't care about the websocket implementation.

I've identified the price data CSS selectors for you and created a scraping configuration to be used with the open source browser extension https://github.com/get-set-fetch/extension.

"eLtI4gnapZTLDsIgEEV/hejGLrC+F25N3OrCpUlD6FhIWmiY0f6+1Hd9EJsuSEguGRg4h8fSlS0Km/r3ZesjHR0g2zrtKzL2IYg1wOqLZ2hEicrSwxhFVOIyjquqGmpzAiRtsqG0RSxv5TVg7EDkvC7AD9etmqJlQBz9ONRW8HvgJ06UwD2HpCV/gtpFylFnC39A/s51A3qphMlg94ruBbtNCe5iMr5/EP/S3ICZf4H5myP/0tv3rSIm/oiQjBmlS0OKS6XzdDCJ9iYQT8PxLBzPw/Ei6rWwpZ0dZ2cMF5M="

Inside the extension do: new project > config hash > paste the above hash (without the quotes) > save, scrape, view results > export as csv.

Disclaimer: I'm the extension author.

Answer (score 0):

The page has probably changed since the original post, but it seems quite scrapable with static HTML at present. This could be run in a polling manner:

```js
const axios = require("axios"); // 1.4.0
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const url = "<Your URL>";

axios
  .get(url)
  .then(({data: html}) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const data = [...$("table")].map(table => {
      const headers = [...$(table).find("th")]
        .map(e => $(e).text().trim());
      return [...$(table).find("> tbody > tr")].map(tr =>
        Object.fromEntries(
          [...$(tr).find("> td")]
            .map((td, i) => [headers[i], $(td).text().trim()])
            .filter(e => Boolean(e[1]))
        )
      );
    });
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Otherwise, you could use a browser automation library like Puppeteer and idle on the page, continuously scraping whenever an update occurs.

Now, all of the above assumed a Node environment. I see you have a `componentDidMount`, so you may be writing front-end code. In that case, you probably want to proxy the API request and handle parsing in your server API, assuming you have one. If you really are making the request from the front end, you may need to proxy the request anyway to handle CORS. Once you finally get the response, there's no need to use Cheerio, since that's a port of jQuery for Node. Use jQuery or the build-in DOM parser.